# How to add a new array in my Code that is called categories and print it out together with codes from a text file that had been saved to arrays

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

Right now I want to add a new array called "category" in my code. I am supposed to add an array and can let it print out with my other codes. I have tried the if-statement for the categories in the year for 2014. It tells me that there are no syntax errors, but that nothing is printing. I also want to format my code so they all are in columns and look organize. I tried a few ways, but nothing changed. What I put right now does not have the format, it is not that important, but if someone can help, it is very appreciated.

```
enter code here
/**
 * Write a program to calculate the average category, pressure, and wind 
speed of Atlantic hurricanes that have occurred between a given year 
range. Also, tally the number of storms in each category according to the 
Saffir-Simpson scale.
 *
 * Steven Liu
 * 10/25/2019
 */
import java.util.Scanner;      
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class HurricaneSelector
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        File fileName = new File ("hurricanedata.txt");
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(fileName);
        int totalYear;

        System.out.println("What year do you want from 1995 - 2015(e.g. 
2004 2005): ");
        int startYear = in.nextInt();
        int endYear = in.nextInt();

        totalYear = endYear - startYear;
        int Arrays;
        int counter = 0;

        while (inFile.hasNextLine()) 
        {
            inFile.nextLine();
            counter++;
        }
        inFile.close ();

        int finalSpeed = 0;
        int [] year = new int[counter];
        String [] month = new String[counter];
        String [] name = new String[counter];
        int [] pressure = new int[counter];
        int [] windSpeed = new int[counter];
        int index = 0; 
        int [] category = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};


        inFile = new Scanner(fileName);
        while (inFile.hasNext())
        {
            year[index] = inFile.nextInt();
            month[index] = inFile.next();
            pressure[index] = inFile.nextInt();
            windSpeed[index] = inFile.nextInt();
            name[index] = inFile.next();
            finalSpeed += windSpeed[index];
            index++;
    }
    double windSpeedMPH;
    double winds;

    if (startYear == 1995)
    {
        for (int n = 0; year[n] < endYear + 1; n++)
        {
            System.out.println(year[n] + "     " + name[n] + "     " + pressure[n] + "     " + windSpeed[n] * 1.15078);
            windSpeedMPH = windSpeed[n] * 1.15078;
        }
    }
    else if (startYear == 1996)
    {
        for (int n = 11; year[n] < endYear + 1; n++)
        {
            System.out.println(year[n] + "     " + name[n] + "     " + pressure[n] + "     " + windSpeed[n] * 1.15078);
            windSpeedMPH = windSpeed[n] * 1.15078;
        }
    }
    else if (startYear == 1997)
    {
        for (int n = 20; year[n] < endYear + 1; n++)
        {
            System.out.println(year[n] + "     " + name[n] + "     " + pressure[n] + "     " + windSpeed[n] * 1.15078);
            windSpeedMPH = windSpeed[n] * 1.15078;
        }
    }
    else if (startYear == 1998)
    {
        for (int n = 23; year[n] < endYear + 1; n++)
        {
            System.out.println(year[n] + "     " + name[n] + "     " + pressure[n] + "     " + windSpeed[n] * 1.15078);
            windSpeedMPH = windSpeed[n] * 1.15078;
        }
    }
    else if (startYear == 1999)
    {
        for (int n = 33; year[n] < endYear + 1; n++)
        {
            System.out.println(year[n] + "     " + name[n] + "     " + pressure[n] + "     " + windSpeed[n] * 1.15078);
            windSpeedMPH = windSpeed[n] * 1.15078;
        }
    }
    else if (startYear == 2000)
    {
        for (int n = 41; year[n] < endYear + 1; n++)
        {
            System.out.println(year[n] + "     " + name[n] + "     " + pressure[n] + "     " + windSpeed[n] * 1.15078);
            windSpeedMPH = windSpeed[n] * 1.15078;
        }
    }
    else if (startYear == 2001)
    {
        for (int n = 49; year[n] < endYear + 1; n++)
        {
            System.out.println(year[n] + "     " + name[n] + "     " + pressure[n] + "     " + windSpeed[n] * 1.15078);
            windSpeedMPH = windSpeed[n] * 1.15078;
        }
    }
    else if (startYear == 2002)
    {
        for (int n = 58; year[n] < endYear + 1; n++)
        {
            System.out.println(year[n] + "     " + name[n] + "     " + pressure[n] + "     " + windSpeed[n] * 1.15078);
            windSpeedMPH = windSpeed[n] * 1.15078;
        }
    }
    else if (startYear == 2003)
    {
        for (int n = 62; year[n] < endYear + 1; n++)
        {
            System.out.println(year[n] + "     " + name[n] + "     " + pressure[n] + "     " + windSpeed[n] * 1.15078);
            windSpeedMPH = windSpeed[n] * 1.15078;
        }
    }
    else if (startYear == 2004)
    {
        for (int n = 69; year[n] < endYear + 1; n++)
        {
            System.out.println(year[n] + "     " + name[n] + "     " + pressure[n] + "     " + windSpeed[n] * 1.15078);
            windSpeedMPH = windSpeed[n] * 1.15078;
        }
    }
    else if (startYear == 2005)
    {
        for (int n = 78; year[n] < endYear + 1; n++)
        {
            System.out.println(year[n] + "     " + name[n] + "     " + pressure[n] + "     " + windSpeed[n] * 1.15078);
            windSpeedMPH = windSpeed[n] * 1.15078;
        }
    }
    else if (startYear == 2006)
    {
        for (int n = 93; year[n] < endYear + 1; n++)
        {
            System.out.println(year[n] + "     " + name[n] + "     " + pressure[n] + "     " + windSpeed[n] * 1.15078);
            windSpeedMPH = windSpeed[n] * 1.15078;
        }
    }
    else if (startYear == 2007)
    {
        for (int n = 98; year[n] < endYear + 1; n++)
        {
            System.out.println(year[n] + "     " + name[n] + "     " + pressure[n] + "     " + windSpeed[n] * 1.15078);
            windSpeedMPH = windSpeed[n] * 1.15078;
        }
    }
    else if (startYear == 2008)
    {
        for (int n = 104; year[n] < endYear + 1; n++)
        {
            System.out.println(year[n] + "     " + name[n] + "     " + pressure[n] + "     " + windSpeed[n] * 1.15078);
            windSpeedMPH = windSpeed[n] * 1.15078;
        }
    }
    else if (startYear == 2009)
    {
        for (int n = 112; year[n] < endYear + 1; n++)
        {
            System.out.println(year[n] + "     " + name[n] + "     " + pressure[n] + "     " + windSpeed[n] * 1.15078);
            windSpeedMPH = windSpeed[n] * 1.15078;
        }
    }
    else if (startYear == 2010)
    {
        for (int n = 115; year[n] < endYear + 1; n++)
        {
            System.out.println(year[n] + "     " + name[n] + "     " + pressure[n] + "     " + windSpeed[n] * 1.15078);
            windSpeedMPH = windSpeed[n] * 1.15078;
        }
    }
    else if (startYear == 2011)
    {
        for (int n = 127; year[n] < endYear + 1; n++)
        {
            System.out.println(year[n] + "     " + name[n] + "     " + pressure[n] + "     " + windSpeed[n] * 1.15078);
            windSpeedMPH = windSpeed[n] * 1.15078;
        }
    }
    else if (startYear == 2012)
    {
        for (int n = 134; year[n] < endYear + 1; n++)
        {
            System.out.println(year[n] + "     " + name[n] + "     " + pressure[n] + "     " + windSpeed[n] * 1.15078);
            windSpeedMPH = windSpeed[n] * 1.15078;
        }
    }
    else if (startYear == 2013)
    {
        for (int n = 144; year[n] < endYear + 1; n++)
        {
            System.out.println(year[n] + "     " + name[n] + "     " + pressure[n] + "     " + windSpeed[n] * 1.15078);
            windSpeedMPH = windSpeed[n] * 1.15078;
        }
    }
    else if (startYear == 2014)
    {
        for (int n = 146; year[n] <= endYear; n++)
        {
            windSpeedMPH = windSpeed[n] * 1.15078;
            if(windSpeedMPH < 96)
            {
                category[n] = category [0];
            }
            else if (windSpeedMPH< 111)
            {
                category[n] = category [1];
            }
            else if (windSpeedMPH< 130)
            {
                category[n] = category [2];
            }
            else if (windSpeedMPH < 157)
            {
                category[n] = category [3];
            }
            else if (windSpeedMPH > 156)
            {
                category[n] = category [4];
            }
            System.out.printf("%d     %-10s%8d%17d%17.2f%n", year[n], name[n], category[0], pressure[n], windSpeed[n] * 1.15078);
        }
    }
    else if (startYear == 2015)
    {
        for (int n = 52; year[n] <= endYear; n++)
        {
            System.out.println(year[n] + "     " + name[n] + "     " + pressure[n] + "     " + windSpeed[n] * 1.15078);
            windSpeedMPH = windSpeed[n] * 1.15078;
        }

    }  
}
}
```

The expected out put should be something like (The middle is supposed to be the categories, I put in random numbers for the example output. The actual numbers of the categories is shown in my code with the array in the beginning and the if-statement in the 2014 part) :

```
2011     Irene     3   942     120.83189999999999
2011     Katia     4   942     138.09359999999998
2011     Maria     1   983     80.5546
2011     Nate      1   994     74.80069999999999
2011     Ophelia   4   940     138.09359999999998
2011     Philippe  3   976     92.0624
2011     Rina      2   966     115.07799999999999
2012     Chris     2   974     86.3085
2012     Ernesto   1   973     97.8163
2012     Gordon    4   965     109.32409999999999
2012     Isaac     2   965     80.5546
2012     Kirk      4   970     103.57019999999999
2012     Leslie    4   968     80.5546
2012     Michael   4   964     115.07799999999999
2012     Nadine    4   978     92.0624
2012     Rafael    2   969     92.0624
2012     Sandy     4   940     115.07799999999999
2013     Humberto  3   979     92.0624
2013     Ingrid    5   983     86.3085
2014     Arthur    3   973     97.8163
2014     Bertha    2   998     80.5546
2014     Cristobal 2   965     86.3085
2014     Edouard   4   955     120.83189999999999
2014     Fay       3   983     80.5546
2014     Gonzalo   4   940     143.8475
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int n=0;
while(year[n]<=endYear)
{
 if(year[n]>=startYear)
{
        System.out.println(year[n] + "     " + name[n] + "     " + pressure[n] + "     " + windSpeed[n] * 1.15078);
        windSpeedMPH = windSpeed[n] * 1.15078;
}
n++;
}
```

Not really sure what you are asking for but
You should change your if else nested statement to loop instead

Comment: Ok, this helps me also. Made me code way easier, thanks a lot.